# Rails updating existing object with associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Forgive me.   I am in Vegas and must just be dumb.

I have an Article model with many Attachments.   And an Attachment model which belongs to an Article.   So, if I create an article without an attachment, then I want to edit it and add an attachment I run into something interesting.

When my Article edit action looks like this:

```
def edit
end
```

When I update my article with an attachment, it doesn't work.   But, when I update my article with an empty name and an empty content, I break the validations set up in my model as I'd expect.  Here's the params hash when I do that.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"1X8Jr3Om2lrnhNEojTppKGRpRwF8/fidVHdC+H4UMPkAiF/oPF9yxB6j0jfL/I7VzUcDtTIh2iB+B7b19XN2Ug==", "article"=>{"name"=>"", "content"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update article", "business_id"=>"1", "id"=>"43"}
```

Now, when I change my edit action to this:

```
def edit
 @article.attachments.build
end
```

When I update an article with an attachment, I get it and it works.   BUT my validation is no longer checked.   When I submit a ticket with an empty name and hash, it just returns back to the show page, as if updated, keeping the existing data.

I'm wondering why.

Here's my params hash when I do this with the edit action above:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SQon3+gX/5vg9HKTUr/hWgRAagHIrA2PYexrq6Umasqc/XGYp+5XBRnTcYwUeQanrW4utYZwLzJLnJ+mLkEsYQ==", "commit"=>"Update article", "business_id"=>"1", "id"=>"43"}
```

Note, the params[:article] doesn't exist here as it does on the first, which is why, obviously, validations are skipped.   My question, though, is why?

I wouldn't think this would be that hard, so I'm blaming Vegas :).

Update with views:

attachments/_form which exists if I call build on a new or edit for the article, but doesn't exist on edit unless build is in the edit, but I can click a JS button which links to the new action of the attachment in that case.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :attachments, child_index: index do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.input :file, as: :file, label: "File ##{index += 1}" %>
  <%= ff.input :file_cache, as: :hidden %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the article form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@business, @article]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <%= f.error :content_count, class: "alert-error" %>
<div id="attachments">
  <h3>Attachments</h3>
  <% index = 0 %>
  <%= render partial: "attachments/form", locals: { f: f, index: 0 } %>
</div>
<p>
  <% if !@article.persisted? %>
    <%= link_to "Add another file", new_attachment_path, remote: true,
    id: "add_file", data: { params: {index: @article.attachments.size} } %>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Add another file", edit_attachment_path, remote: true,
      id: "add_file", data: { params: {index: @article.attachments.size} } %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary" %>
```

I tried to add an if statement here in case I could send this request to different "actions" in the attachments controller, but it just replicates the issue, not corrects it, so you can ignore the if as I will remove it.

Here is the attachments controller though:

```
def new
  @index = params[:index].to_i
  @article = Article.new
  @article.attachments.build
 render layout: false
end

def edit
  @index = params[:index].to_i
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.attachments.build
  render layout: false
end
```

One more edit adding the JS:

```
ready = ->
  $("#add_file").on "ajax:success", (event, data) ->
    $("#attachments").append data
    $(this).data "params", { index: $("#attachments div.file").length }
```

Comment: Show the view(s) that generate that edit page.

Comment: Added as requested.   I can add more too. :).   I've tried using different things in the view too, but it all just repeats the problem.    There is JS code that creates the form field when I click the link which is standard stuff provided by Rails 4 in Action as a basis.

Comment: are you nesting the params? Are you whitelisting the params in your article controller? I would remove that build. I would focus on getting them to pass in the params hash. Then use the attachments in the params to create the attachments from the articles update action.

Comment: Yes.   They are whitelisted correctly.   I can send that, but as mentioned, it works if I build it in edit.   If I don't, it STILL works, but the file is nil because it's not actually uploading in that case.   Meaning it inserts an attachment with a nil file, which is bad :).

Answer (score 0):

When you said "When I update an article with an attachment" I assume you meant that you're clicking one of the "Add another file" buttons? As you mention in your new comment, there's JS code that creates the form field when you click the link.

Problem here is that actually it creates a whole `<form>`, and so when that's submitted it's coming through with just the file/attachment because it's not the same form as the one where your `:name` and `:content` etc. are.

You need to use your own JS there so that it creates just the fields (not a whole form) for your attachments.

Comment: Hmm.   That would be bad news then as I literally know nothing about JS.  From what I can tell though I didn't think it was rendering the form, merely calling and appending the form above.   I'll update my question with that, just in case it helps.

Comment: Put the JS/coffee up.   And, yes, when I use build in the edit action the form is there so I only have to hit the Add another file link to add multiples.   With the build in the edit action it works fine.   But then, as you point out, the article attributes are gone when I remove them and no validations take place.   I'll look at the JS being why that happens, but, I'm WAY dumb on JS :).

Comment: The code you've posted is what happens after the ajax response comes back from the server. You didn't write the code that creates the form, that's part of Rails's `jquery_ujs.js`. But trust me, this is the problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15845797/152786 for another SO post about this.

Comment: Looks like the cocoon gem actually appears to make it all go :)

Comment: Spoke too soon.   Cocoon allows the build to take place without expressing it in edit, but still skips validations :).